# Compare scores between pre/post on different rows in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I have an excel file that has people's responses to questions over time and in multiple rows. I need do a comparison of the first rating with the last rating to see if there was an increase or decrease. Then I have to summarize the number of increases and decreases per question.  The only tool I have to use is standard excel (no macros or power query etc.)

I have tried using pivot tables using max/min on the date field but because the pre/post dates are different for everyone that doesn't seem to work.  Does anyone have any ideas on a set of steps I could use to get there?

Starting place is this table:

| Name | Date | Question 1 | Question 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | 1/1/23 | 1 | 2 |
| Joe | 1/5/23 | 3 | 3 |
| Sally | 2/1/23 | 4 | 8 |
| Sally | 2/6/23 | 6 | 7 |

Ending place is something similar to this table:

| Question | Number increase | Number decrease |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Question 1 | 2 | 0 |
| Question 2 | 1 | 1 |

Thank you.

Comment: How many questions do you have? And if someone answers the same question 4 times, do you only care about the first and last times?

Comment: There are 18 questions and I only care about the first and last times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your table is placed in range A1:D5, try this:

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name | Date | Question 1 | Question 2 |  | Name | Date min | Date max | Question 1 | Question 2 |  |  | Number increase | Number decrease | Number stall |
| Joe | 44927 | 1 | 2 |  | =IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A2,A2)=1,A2,"") | =IF(F2="","",AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(A:A=F2)*B:B,1)) | =IF(F2="","",AGGREGATE(14,6,1/(A:A=F2)*B:B,1)) | =IF(F2="","",SUMIFS(C:C,$A:$A,$F2,$B:$B,$G2)-SUMIFS(C:C,$A:$A,$F2,$B:$B,$H2)) | =IF(G2="","",SUMIFS(D:D,$A:$A,$F2,$B:$B,$G2)-SUMIFS(D:D,$A:$A,$F2,$B:$B,$H2)) |  | Question 1 | =COUNTIF(I:I,"<0") | =COUNTIF(I:I,">0") | =COUNTIF(I:I,"=0") |
| Joe | 45047 | 3 | 3 |  | =IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A3,A3)=1,A3,"") | =IF(F3="","",AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(A:A=F3)*B:B,1)) | =IF(F3="","",AGGREGATE(14,6,1/(A:A=F3)*B:B,1)) | =IF(F3="","",SUMIFS(C:C,$A:$A,$F3,$B:$B,$G3)-SUMIFS(C:C,$A:$A,$F3,$B:$B,$H3)) | =IF(G3="","",SUMIFS(D:D,$A:$A,$F3,$B:$B,$G3)-SUMIFS(D:D,$A:$A,$F3,$B:$B,$H3)) |  | Question 2 | =COUNTIF(J:J,"<0") | =COUNTIF(J:J,">0") | =COUNTIF(J:J,"=0") |
| Sally | 44928 | 4 | 8 |  | =IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A4,A4)=1,A4,"") | =IF(F4="","",AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(A:A=F4)*B:B,1)) | =IF(F4="","",AGGREGATE(14,6,1/(A:A=F4)*B:B,1)) | =IF(F4="","",SUMIFS(C:C,$A:$A,$F4,$B:$B,$G4)-SUMIFS(C:C,$A:$A,$F4,$B:$B,$H4)) | =IF(G4="","",SUMIFS(D:D,$A:$A,$F4,$B:$B,$G4)-SUMIFS(D:D,$A:$A,$F4,$B:$B,$H4)) |  |  |  |  |  |
| Sally | 45079 | 6 | 7 |  | =IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A5,A5)=1,A5,"") | =IF(F5="","",AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(A:A=F5)*B:B,1)) | =IF(F5="","",AGGREGATE(14,6,1/(A:A=F5)*B:B,1)) | =IF(F5="";"";SUMIFS(C:C;$A:$A;$F5;$B:$B;$G5)-SUMIFS(C:C;$A:$A;$F5;$B:$B;$H5)) | =IF(G5="";"";SUMIFS(D:D;$A:$A;$F5;$B:$B;$G5)-SUMIFS(D:D;$A:$A;$F5;$B:$B;$H5)) |  |  |  |  |  |

Answer (score 1):

There are better ways, but still:

```
=HSTACK(VSTACK("Question",TOCOL(C1:E1)),VSTACK("Increase",TOCOL(BYCOL(C2:E13,LAMBDA(y,SUM(BYROW(UNIQUE(A2:A13),LAMBDA(x,N((FILTER(y,(B2:B13=MAXIFS(B2:B13,A2:A13,x))*(A2:A13=x))-FILTER(y,(B2:B13=MINIFS(B2:B13,A2:A13,x))*(A2:A13=x)))>0)))))))),VSTACK("Decrease",TOCOL(BYCOL(C2:E13,LAMBDA(y,SUM(BYROW(UNIQUE(A2:A13),LAMBDA(x,N((FILTER(y,(B2:B13=MAXIFS(B2:B13,A2:A13,x))*(A2:A13=x))-FILTER(y,(B2:B13=MINIFS(B2:B13,A2:A13,x))*(A2:A13=x)))<0)))))))))
```

Result:

[image]

With your given data:

```
=HSTACK(VSTACK("Question",TOCOL(C1:D1)),VSTACK("Increase",TOCOL(BYCOL(C2:D5,LAMBDA(y,SUM(BYROW(UNIQUE(A2:A5),LAMBDA(x,N((FILTER(y,(B2:B5=MAXIFS(B2:B5,A2:A5,x))*(A2:A5=x))-FILTER(y,(B2:B5=MINIFS(B2:B5,A2:A5,x))*(A2:A5=x)))>0)))))))),VSTACK("Decrease",TOCOL(BYCOL(C2:D5,LAMBDA(y,SUM(BYROW(UNIQUE(A2:A5),LAMBDA(x,N((FILTER(y,(B2:B5=MAXIFS(B2:B5,A2:A5,x))*(A2:A5=x))-FILTER(y,(B2:B5=MINIFS(B2:B5,A2:A5,x))*(A2:A5=x)))<0)))))))))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This is extremely helpful.  Thank you.  Would it change much if I were to look at any increase between a persons surveys, rather than just the first/last?

Comment: Now it compares values with max date and min date for same person. Evaluating change between every following 2 dates for same person would be different logic

Answer (score 0):

There are prenty of sub-optimal options, including this one. Since your data are already pivoted, then having a clean solution might be difficult. You'll probably find better answers because this one requires your data to be properly sorted.

You could start by grabbing a copy of your data and filtering out the rows that don't represent the FIRST or LAST records for each person.

Something like this cell E2 would label each row, making sure your data are sorted by Name and Date.

```
=IF(A2<>A1,"FIRST",IF(A2<>A3,"LAST","NA"))
```

Once your data are cleansed and you have only the FIRST and LAST for each peson, then create helper columns to evaluate each question, which compares the first answer to last answer.

Cell F2 formula:

```
=IF($A2=$A1,C2-C1,0)
```

Drag if over and down.

Lastly, you can summarize by counting the number of cells >0 for  increase, and number of cells <0 for decrease.

```
Cell F12 formula: =COUNTIF(F2:F9,">0")

Cell F13 formula: =COUNTIF(F2:F9,"<0")
```

Drag those across.

| Name | Date | Q1 | Q2 | Filtered | Q1_check | Q2_check |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | 44927 | 1 | 2 | =IF(A2<>A1,"FIRST",IF(A2<>A3,"LAST","NA")) | =IF($A2=$A1,C2-C1,0) | =IF($A2=$A1,D2-D1,0) |
| Joe | 44931 | 3 | 3 |  |  |  |
| Sally | 44958 | 4 | 8 |  |  |  |
| Sally | 44963 | 16 | 7 |  |  |  |
| Henry | 44927 | 2 | 1 |  |  |  |
| Henry | 44958 | 1 | 6 |  |  |  |
| Jack | 44958 | 1 | 2 |  |  |  |
| Jack | 44963 | 3 | 2 |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | SUMMARY | Q1 | Q2 |
|  |  |  |  | Increased | =COUNTIF(F2:F9,">0") | =COUNTIF(G2:G9,">0") |
|  |  |  |  | Decreased | =COUNTIF(F2:F9,"<0") | =COUNTIF(G2:G9,"<0") |

[image]